# DbDataRecord - entry.CurrentValues and entry.originalValues are same

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

i'm using Entity Framework 4.1 and i have my DbContext Override SaveChanges to Audit Property Change. The code returning null value from 'GetEntryValueInString'. Its coz "if (entry.Entity is EntityObject)" this condition is failed in all cases. if Im commenting the condition im having another problem like CurrentValues and OriginalValues are getting same.

```
namespace mymodel
 {
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public partial class DbEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbEntities ()
        : base("name=DbEntities ")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<DBAudit> DBAudits { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    List<DBAudit> auditTrailList = new List<DBAudit>();

    public enum AuditActions
    {
        I,
        U,
        D
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {

        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); // Important!

        ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;


        IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified);
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntryEntity in changes)
        {
            if (!stateEntryEntity.IsRelationship &&
                    stateEntryEntity.Entity != null &&
                        !(stateEntryEntity.Entity is DBAudit))
            {//is a normal entry, not a relationship
                DBAudit audit = this.AuditTrailFactory(stateEntryEntity, UserName);
                auditTrailList.Add(audit);
            }
        }

        if (auditTrailList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var audit in auditTrailList)
            {//add all audits 
                //this.AddToDBAudit(audit);
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    private DBAudit AuditTrailFactory(ObjectStateEntry entry, string UserName)
    {
        DBAudit audit = new DBAudit();

        audit.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
        audit.TableName = entry.EntitySet.Name;
        audit.UserId = UserName;

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {//entry is Added 
            audit.NewData = GetEntryValueInString(entry, false);
            audit.Actions = AuditActions.I.ToString();
        }
        else if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        {//entry in deleted
            audit.OldData = GetEntryValueInString(entry, true);
            audit.Actions = AuditActions.D.ToString();
        }
        else
        {//entry is modified
            audit.OldData = GetEntryValueInString(entry, true);
            audit.NewData = GetEntryValueInString(entry, false);
            audit.Actions = AuditActions.U.ToString();

            IEnumerable<string> modifiedProperties = entry.GetModifiedProperties();
            //assing collection of mismatched Columns name as serialized string 
            //audit.TableName = XMLSerializationHelper.XmlSerialize(modifiedProperties.ToArray());
        }

        return audit;
    }

    private string GetEntryValueInString(ObjectStateEntry entry, bool isOrginal)
    {
        if (entry.Entity is EntityObject)
        {
            object target = CloneEntity((EntityObject)entry.Entity);
            foreach (string propName in entry.GetModifiedProperties())
            {
                object setterValue = null;
                if (isOrginal)
                {
                    //Get orginal value 
                    setterValue = entry.OriginalValues[propName];
                }
                else
                {
                    //Get orginal value 
                    setterValue = entry.CurrentValues[propName];
                }
                //Find property to update 
                PropertyInfo propInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
                //update property with orgibal value 
                if (setterValue == DBNull.Value)
                {//
                    setterValue = null;
                }
                propInfo.SetValue(target, setterValue, null);
            }//end foreach

            XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(target.GetType());
            XDocument document = new XDocument();

            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = document.CreateWriter())
            {
                formatter.Serialize(xmlWriter, target);
            }
            return document.Root.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public EntityObject CloneEntity(EntityObject obj)
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcSer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        dcSer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        EntityObject newObject = (EntityObject)dcSer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
        return newObject;
    }

    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Holiday> Holidays { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TimeZone> TimeZones { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class DbEntities
{
    public enum AuditActions
    {
        I,
        U,
        D
    }
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {

            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); // Important!

            ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

            IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified);
            foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntryEntity in changes)
            {
                if (stateEntryEntity.EntitySet.Name != "MobileLoginDatas" && stateEntryEntity.EntitySet.Name != "SystemLookUps")//eliminate these tables
                {
                    if (SessionData.userId != null && SessionData.userId != 0) //execute only after user login
                    {
                        if (!stateEntryEntity.IsRelationship &&
                                stateEntryEntity.Entity != null &&
                                    !(stateEntryEntity.Entity is DBAudit))
                        {
                            DBAudit audit = new DBAudit();
                            audit.RevisionStamp = DateTime.Now;
                            audit.UserId = SessionData.userId;
                            audit.TableName = stateEntryEntity.EntitySet.Name;
                            audit.IPAddress = SessionData.clientIpAddress;

                            if (stateEntryEntity.State == EntityState.Added)
                            {//entry is Added 
                                audit.Data = DictionaryToJsonConverter(GetEntryValueString(stateEntryEntity, false));

                                audit.Action = AuditActions.I.ToString();
                            }
                            else if (stateEntryEntity.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                            {//entry in deleted
                                audit.Data = DictionaryToJsonConverter(GetEntryValueString(stateEntryEntity, true));
                                audit.Action = AuditActions.D.ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {//entry is modified
                                audit.Data = DictionaryToJsonConverter(GetEntryValueString(stateEntryEntity, false));
                                audit.Action = AuditActions.U.ToString();
                            }
                            this.Entry(audit).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


      //  }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    ///convert the data to json
    string DictionaryToJsonConverter(Dictionary<String, Object> dict)
    {
        var entries = dict.Select(d =>
            string.Format("'{0}': {1}", d.Key, string.Join(",", d.Value)));
        return "{" + string.Join(",", entries) + "}";
    }
    private Dictionary<string, object> GetEntryValueString(ObjectStateEntry entry, Boolean isOriginal)
    {
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var values = (IDataRecord) null;
        if (isOriginal)
        {
            values = entry.OriginalValues;
        }
        else
        {
            values = entry.CurrentValues;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < values.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            keyValues.Add(values.GetName(i), values.GetValue(i));
        }
        return keyValues;
    }
}
```